# On click a button should download a dynamic shortcut link in html

Tags: html, url

I want a button so that on click that button it downloads the shortcut of the url. How can i do this. For example say in facebook site have a button..when i click this button it will automatically download/create a shortcut on my desktop of facebook/given url.

Comment: share with us what have you done so far. SO is to help and not write code for you

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have no clue. How to do this. that's why i am writing here. The problem is I want to create a shortcut icon on desktop by clicking a button. The shortcut will open a particular website.

Comment: buddy consider SO as your busy colleague. We can help you fix your issue but not do everything for you. This is how it works

Answer (score 0):

Use this Button to download the specific Img Use this Code

```html
<a href="url" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Comment: I want to create a shortcut icon on desktop.....on clicking that shortcut it will open a perticular website....say i clicked a desktop icon it will open www.facebook.com.....it will not work